# Google + sign in within app

Tags: ios, ios7, google-plus

I want to integrate Google+ sign in functionality to my app. I have used Google+ sdk , but it redirect to safari to sign in to google , I want to open that web dialog within my application. Can anybody help me on that thing?

Comment: remove the url scheme in plist

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik not working...it will redirect to goole + but will not return to our app by removing url scheme

Comment: That's not supported by the SDK.

Comment: Check this link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

Comment: @Steve Any way to doing this without using SDK?

Comment: @Steve I want to do this because apple has rejected one of my app in which I was using sign in feature by leaving my app for authentication. They suggested me to do authentication within application

Comment: @Steve We can do that. Check FlipKart Application in ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it. By inheriting UIApplication class and then handling url in web view. Here is code:

Add Google+ FrameWork to your project.

Now, on authentication call, catch that URL by inhereting UIAPPLICATION Class.

```
- (IBAction)btnGooglePlusTap:(id)sender
{
   [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate];
}

SubClassUIApplication.h 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define ApplicationOpenGoogleAuthNotification @"GoogleFriendInvitationPosted"

@interface SubClassUIApplication : UIApplication

@end


#import "SubClassUIApplication.h"

@implementation SubClassUIApplication

- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"googlechrome-x-callback:"])
    {
        return NO;//This will prevent call to Google Chrome App if installed.
    }
    else if([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"])
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ApplicationOpenGoogleAuthNotification object:url];

        return NO;// Here we will pass URL to notification and from notification observer , we will load web view.
    }
    else if ([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"com.google"])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super openURL:url];
}

@end
```

Set this subclass as principal class in info.plist file.

Now open URL to web view

```
- (void)catchNotificationforGooglePlusSharing:(NSNotification *)notiofication
{
    NSURL *u=(NSURL *)notiofication.object;

    UINavigationController *navWebView =(UINavigationController *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewNavController"];

    WebViewController *vcWebView = navWebView.viewControllers[0];
    vcWebView.webURL = u;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:navWebView animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

Now in webviewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLRequest *req= [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:webURL];

    [webvGoogle loadRequest:req];
}
#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate method
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    BOOL canHandle = [GPPURLHandler handleURL:request.URL sourceApplication:@"com.apple.mobilesafari" annotation:nil];

    if(canHandle == YES)
    {


        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
        {

        }];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error in loading : %@",error.description);
}
```

Don't forget to register your class for ApplicationOpenGoogleAuthNotification notification.

Comment: well yes..I will share tomorrow

Comment: @BAYMAX If you want code please comment here, I will share my code with you.

Comment: @BAYMAX ...Hope now you will be happy

Answer (score 1):

You can use GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch from [Google Toolbox for Mac - OAuth 2 Controllers](https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/).

```
#import <GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h>

GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *googleAuthViewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
                       initWithScope:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email"
                       clientID:kClientId
                       clientSecret:kSecretId
                       keychainItemName:@"GooglePlus_Sample_App"
                       delegate:self
                       finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:googleAuthViewController animated:YES];
```

This is a sample found here http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/02/22/google-sign-on-with-1password/ where you can find full sample project.

Comment: I have handle authorization my self from webview same concept like this...and it works like charm and also help me to make decision whether I want to open any url within app or in safari. But thank you for your response.